# Use Google Calendar API Client Library v3 on Winforms targeting .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a WinForms app targeting Net Framework 3.5 and I would like to use the Google Calendar API Client Library v3.

Until two weeks ago, I was using the Calendar API Client Library v2, but because it is now depricated it does no longer work.

The problem is that the Google Calendar API Client Library v3 targets Net Framework 4.0 and I cannot use it in my app.

Is there a previous version of the Google Calendar API Client Library v3 that targets Net Framework 3.5? I would like to use OAuth2 like the way explained in this article if it is possible: http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/

Comment: No there isn't a version of the client lib for 3.5.  Your only option is to do it with out the client lib and design your own system making each of the calls yourself.  Its doable.  This will get you authentication http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: @DaImTo I tried 1.3.0-beta API as suggested by peleyal and works fine with Google Calendar API. So, for now I am ok. By the way congratulation for your site. I found plenty of info there about google API and .NET

Comment: wow sweet. I will need to remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in this blogpost - http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2013/06/announcing-release-of-140-beta_26.html.

From 1.4.0-beta (long long time ago) we started supporting .NET 4.0 or higher, but if you want to get a client library that targets .NET 3.5, you should download it from here: 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/calendar/v3/csharp?lv=1.3.0-beta.

You can also find working samples here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=contrib#hg%2F1.3.0-beta%2FGenerated%2FZipFiles.

1.3.0-beta is NOT REALLY RECOMMENDED. I would recommend you to upgrade to (at least) .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thank you peleyal, 1.3.0-beta works fine with google calendar api